# Missing Accounts in Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I've an app that uses Android accounts - GoogleLoginService on (< 2.1) and AccountManager on 2.1 or greater. the app works fine on phones, but doesn't work on any of the emulators.

When I try adding accounts in emulator, it fails. In 1.6, option doesn't even exist.

Is there a workaround? I heard that there is a custom system.img that has Accounts inbuilt, but cant find one. I need it for 1.6, 2.1, 2.2

Comment: "When I try adding accounts in emulator, it fails." -- define "it fails". I can add accounts just fine in the 2.2 emulator at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are your emulators using the Google APIs versions of Android? If not, use the SDK manager to get those versions of Android, and create a new emulator with one of them as the target.